# linux bash script log output

Tags: mysql, linux, shell, logfile

Im having trouble getting output into my log file in my script. Backup runs successfully but the logfile is empty. WHen I run the script I get "Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure." so at least that should be in a log file. (I am using a .key file)

```
mysqldump  -u root -p$Pass   --all-databases | gzip > fulldbdmp-$(date +%m%d%Y).dump.gz 2> file.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because, only error from your gzip execution goes into file. To get what you want, use -

`mysqldump  -u root -p$Pass   --all-databases 2>file.log | gzip > fulldbdmp-$(date +%m%d%Y).dump.gz`

Comment: Yep, that all makes sense. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I agree with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44073167/8013693) answer, but it seems, that it is needed to add another parameter (**-v**)  to enable verbose output, like `mysqldump -v -u root -p$Pass   --all-databases 2>file.log | gzip > fulldbdmp-$(date +%m%d%Y).dump.gz`.

Comment: Inspired by [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/14307) and [official docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html)

Comment: Great..cant believe I did not realize it.. Thank you. Spasibo - Vitalik

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you can see the error message on your terminal means it's not going into the log file.

As others have mentioned, you are redirecting stderr from the `gzip` element of the pipeline, not the `mysqldump` element.

If you think about your pipline as a series of elements, it may become clear what's going on:

- `mysqldump -u root -p$Pass --all-databases`
- `gzip > fulldbdmp-$(date +%m%d%Y).dump.gz 2> file.log`

You were probably after this:

- `mysqldump -u root -p$Pass --all-databases 2> file.log`
- `gzip > fulldbdmp-$(date +%m%d%Y).dump.gz`

Which becomes:

```sh
mysqldump -u root -p$Pass --all-databases 2> file.log \ |
  gzip > fulldbdmp-$(date +%m%d%Y).dump.gz
```

---

**Side note:** I would strongly encourage you *not* to ignore the following warning. It is there for a reason. see [6.1.2.1 End-User Guidelines for Password Security](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/password-security-user.html)

> Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure